# Possible to move the hidden text files from $HOME to someplace else?

Tags: files

So there's a whole bunch of files in the $HOME directory which aren't a problem functionally, but visually, they are mildly annoying (I prefer having hidden files visible). The list of files are as follows:

- .bash_history
- .bash_logout
- .bashrc
- .hushlogin
- .ICEauthority
- .nvidia-settings-rc
- .pam_environment
- .profile
- .sudo_as_admin_successful
- .wget-hsts
- .xinputrc

Ideally, I'd like to move anything that is a temporary file to my tmp folder, and any configuration files to a config folder I have, thereby ensuring my $HOME directory contains nothing but folders.

Comment: Most of those files have to be in `$HOME` to work (`.bashrc`, `pam_environment`, `.profile`, etc.). Some of them may be relocated (`.bash_history`).

Comment: you can't, if you move a temporary hidden file, you will just make a save of it (he will be moved, but not removed from your temporary folder despite in $HOME directory where he would be removed), and for other like `.bashrc`, it would be a real problem, if you removed it, you will lost some home configuration (just for this user)

Comment: I see. So I take it there's also no way to edit the options/config files of the applications that created those files in the first place? To specify a new location to save/read those files, that is.

Comment: @muru if we want to move it totally, it needs to edit some files inside `/etc` or `/proc` if we don't want to see another `.bash_history` created inside `$HOME`

Comment: @damadam `.bash_history` can be put somewhere else by setting `HISTFILE` in `~/.bashrc`. You don't need to edit anything in `/etc` for that.

Comment: @hiigaran there already is a location like the one you want (`~/.config` aka [`$XDG_CONFIG_HOME`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/XDG_Base_Directory_support)). Those applications which support it already have their configuration located there. The ones remaining in `$HOME` are those that don't.

Comment: I looked through .bashrc, but found no mention of HISTFILE, other than size specifications. I take it I need to create the line myself? EDIT: Oh wait, found the answer on another question: export HISTFILE=/file/path/.bash_history